# DO action when JavaScript menu is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Dropdown menu items from a text link with JavaScript/CSS.

I have a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/bvy7u2nt/

I need to perform an action when each menu item is clicked on, right now they do nothing.

**HTML**:

```
  <span class="inline-dropdown-menu">
    <a href="">Status<span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="inline-dropdown-menu-list">
      <li class="bottomBorder">
        <a href="" tabindex="-1">Update Order Status</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" tabindex="-1" data-order-item-id="123" data-status-name="pending">Pending Completion</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" tabindex="-1" data-order-item-id="123" data-status-name="completed">Completed</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Show Dropdown Menu when link is clicked
$(function(){

  var inlineDropdownMenuContainer = $(this).find(".inline-dropdown-menu"),
      inlineDropdownMenuLists = $(this).find(".inline-dropdown-menu-list");

  inlineDropdownMenuContainer.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    inlineDropdownMenuLists.hide(); // to hide other drop down
    $(this).find(".inline-dropdown-menu-list:first").toggle();
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop navigation
  });

  $(document).click(function(event){
    //inlineDropdownMenuLists.not(':hidden').hide();

    if (!inlineDropdownMenuContainer.is(event.target) && inlineDropdownMenuContainer.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        inlineDropdownMenuLists.hide();
    }


  });

});
```

---

When each item in the menu above is clicked on, I need to run this code below which shows a dialog window and on confirmation send an AJAX request to update an order status.

I just need help attaching a click even to each button which will get me access to a `var statusName` and `var orderItemId` which will be used in my AJAX request below and there value can come from `datya` attributes `data-order-item-id` and `data-status-name`.

```
            // Show a confirmation Dialog to save new order status or reject and move order back t previous column
            $.confirm({
                'title': 'Update Order Record Status?',
                'message': 'You are about to update this orders Status to : ' + newStatusColumnName + '. <br />Do you wish to Continue?',
                'buttons': {
                    'Yes, Update Order Status': {
                        'class': 'blue',
                        'action': function() {
                            // make AJAX request to update order record status
                          $.ajax({
                              type: 'post',
                              url: 'orders/orderboards/updatestatus',
                              data: 'statusname=' + newStatusColumnName+'&orderitemid='+orderItemId,
                              success: function(result) {
                                if(result.success){
                                    nam.cache.currentItemStatus = newStatusColumnName;
                                  console.log('SUCCESS AJAX Order Status Save: ' + newStatusColumnName+' on order item ID:'+orderItemId);
                                }else{
                                  console.log('FAILURE AJAX did not save ' + newStatusColumnName+' on order item ID:'+orderItemId);
                                }
                              }
                          });
                        }
                    },
                    'Cancel': {
                        'class': 'gray',
                        'action': function() {
                            // need to move the order card back to its previous status column somehow!
                           $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ive updated my answer with a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a event listener to a parent node and look using **event.originalEvent.target** what element inside the node was clicked.
If you somehow tag your links with a class or use your "tabindex=-1" inside the link you can track the click on a link by using only one listener:

```
  $("#manyItems").click(function(event){

      if (event.originalEvent.target.getAttribute("tabindex") == -1) {
      alert("Link was clicked");
      }
});
```

HTML:

```
  <span id="manyItems" class="inline-dropdown-menu">
    <a href="">Status<span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="inline-dropdown-menu-list">
      <li class="bottomBorder">
        <a href="" id="item1" tabindex="-1">Update Order Status</a>
      </li>...
```

Take a look at this working  fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bvy7u2nt/3/

Answer (score 0):

Give `id`s for all these:

```
  <li class="bottomBorder">
    <a href="" tabindex="-1" id="dd1">Update Order Status</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" tabindex="-1" id="dd2">Pending Completion</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" tabindex="-1" id="dd3">Completed</a>
  </li>
```

And in the JavaScript do this:

```
$("#dd1").click(function () {
  alert("You have clicked Update Order Status!");
});
$("#dd1").click(function () {
  alert("You have clicked Pending Completion!");
});
$("#dd1").click(function () {
  alert("You have clicked Completed!");
});
```

Comment: Sorry I should of added that  each of these menu's will be on the page hundreds of times.  It;s a Kanban board and this button will be on each card

Comment: @JasonDavis Add class instead. And use `$(this).data("item-id")` to get which item is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add global `class` for every item you want to be clicked in your list, just like **@Praveen Kumar** mentioned in the comment, see the following example :

```
<ul class="inline-dropdown-menu-list">
     <li class="bottomBorder">
        <a href="" tabindex="-1">Update Order Status</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a class='ajax_link' href="" tabindex="-1" data-order-item-id="123" data-status-name="pending">Pending Completion</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a class='ajax_link' href="" tabindex="-1" data-order-item-id="123" data-status-name="completed">Completed</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

And attach event click to the class `ajax_link`, and get the `statusName` & `orderItemId` of clicked anchor then replace them in dialog, see following code :

```
$('.inline-dropdown-menu-list').on('click','.ajax_link',function(){
        //---HERE  you can get statusName & orderItemId like following
        var statusName = $(this).data('status-name');
        var orderItemId = $(this).data('order-item-id');
        //------------------

        // Show a confirmation Dialog to save new order status or reject and move order back t previous column
        $.confirm({
            'title': 'Update Order Record Status?',
            'message': 'You are about to update this orders Status to : ' + newStatusColumnName + '. <br />Do you wish to Continue?',
            ......
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JavaScript and wrap it around your `$.confirm({`... script.

```
$('.inline-dropdown-menu-list li a').on('click', function(){

});
```

This will execute whenever an `<a>` tag within an `<li>` within the div with the `.inline-dropdown-menu-list` class is clicked.

I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate it...I haven't imported the script for $.confirm to work but if you check the console.log output, you'll see it returns the button you've clicked on:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqLo7d4h/